# How to open this dropbox file in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, executable

As what title said, how should I open [this file?](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7h9sjys6xvkv06p/testing) It was a executable(application/x-executable) file.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it's reasonable to present a random binary file on here without any further information. Even worse, if other users are tempted to run the file (as you've said it's executable), they are extremely vulnerable to any malicious payload. I'm not saying that you are malicious; just that in general this is the reason that presenting this kind of question shouldn't be acceptable. Instead, can you explain what the file is, where you got it from and what you expect Ubuntu to do with it? This might help others to solve your problem safely.

Comment: I wish to scan its vulnerability and find the vulnerability function. I am sorry, I am new. I didn't know this kind of file is malicious. But my quiz requirement ask me to solve this file by scanning its vulnerability by providing the answer How?

Comment: It's not that it necessarily *is* malicious, it's that it very  easily *could* be (which is why I won't be making any attempts to download, let alone open, it). Especially since you're talking about vulnerabilities (which are often exploited to embed or execute some kind of malicious code) - coupled with the fact that you are posting something listed as an application as your first post, it's the sort of thing that can make people nervous (not that I wouldn't still be wary of someone doing that as their 50th post)

Comment: If you're not sure, then do not try to run it. This could compromise your computer. Please don't ask anyone else to try to open or run it, either. To ask how to examine a potentially malicious file is a reasonable question, though.

Comment: Please could you edit your question accordingly?

Comment: Err, its ok that I actually know it was quite dangerous for you guys to open that file trying to help me. But I hope to get any suggestion what to use to open/edit the file. I wish to view the source code or something. Please suggest, thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry, we're not here to do quiz assignments for you. :)

Comment: I am just asking how to open.. :( I did not state you guys to help me answer the Question.. To getting started, I need a way to open and check the codes.

Answer (score 2):

That all depends on what it is...

Generally speaking, you can use `gedit testing` to open the file and view the contents, if it's in some plaintext format.

I see you've tagged the question as "executable", so I assume it's a program of some sort? If that's the case, first verify the following: *Do you know exactly where the file came from originally; Do you trust the source; Do you know exactly what the program is supposed to do?* If the answer to any one of these three questions is "no", then please do NOT try to run it.

If (*and ONLY if*) the answer to all of the above was "yes", though, then in a terminal you would navigate to the folder containing the file and write `chmod +x testing; ./testing` to execute it. The first changes the file permission so that it is executable, and the second tells it to run. I hope you'll forgive me for not trying this myself though, since running anonymous executables isn't really the best of ideas.

Comment: Yes, I trust the source. Actually I am doing some simple challenge. It was all in hex form when opened with gedit. I get this file from removing part of hex(jpg image file) and I get this executable. It was a correct file. Now I wish to open it or scan this file's vulnerability. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Wait, so... it was a jpg, and then you edited it and it ended up recognised as an application? That usually means that you've corrupted it and it can't be opened conventionally. I don't know how to answer the rest of what you're asking, to be honest...

Comment: Erm.. It was actually a Steganography technique. I am a Security student. They can hide information inside an image. I just decrypted them and get this file. It was not corrupted. But the problem now is that I do not know how to open it.

Comment: "corrupted" in as much as "can't be opened in its original context". If you remove something from the plaintext / hex of a JPG, it's unlikely that it can be opened as a jpg any more. The closest I know of to getting the source is some kind of text editor, beyond that I don't know (that you as a security student were surprised at people's mistrust of a random executable slightly baffles me, though)

Comment: I am sososo new to do harm to other people yet. Haha, I just sms my lecturer, unfortunately, he do not have laptop at home. But he said I am going the good direction by having the error when opening it. He ask me to use a debugger to find the vulnerabilities of the file. Do you know any debugger in ubuntu? Can you intro it to me? Thanks..